# how to groupby and merge in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
  Date          Time   Tank       Sales       Quantity        Delivery
  2018-01-01    06:30  1          100         3444            0      
  2018-01-01    07:00  1          200         3144            0
  2018-01-01    05:30  1          100         2900            0      
  2018-01-01    07:30  1          200         2800            0
  2018-01-01    06:30  2          50          3000            0      
  2018-01-01    07:00  2          100         2950            0
  2018-01-01    05:30  2          150         2800            0      
  2018-01-01    07:30  2          100         2704            0
  2018-01-02    06:30  1          100         3444            0      
  2018-01-02    07:00  1          200         3144            0
  2018-01-02    05:30  1          100         2900            50      
  2018-01-02    07:30  1          200         2800            0
  2018-01-02    06:30  2          50          3000            0      
  2018-01-02    07:00  2          100         2950            0
  2018-01-02    05:30  2          150         2800            50     
  2018-01-02    07:30  2          100         2704            0
```

I want to aggregate on a day and tank level to get First and Last Quantity (arranging Time in ascending order) for that day and sum of Sales and Delivery. My desired dataframe would be

```
  Date          Tank    Open    Close   Sales    Delivery
  2018-01-01    1       2900    2800    600      0         
  2018-01-01    2       2800    2704    400      0          
  2018-01-02    1       2900    2800    600      50     
  2018-01-02    2       2800    2704    500      50
```

Currently I am doing following in pandas

This is for to get first and last quantity day and tank level arranging time in ascending order.

```
  data_open_close_inv = data.sort_values(['Date','Tank','Time']).groupby(['Date','Tank'])['Quantity'].agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
```

And then I am aggregating this for total sum of Sales and Delivery

```
data_agg = data.groupby(['Date','Tank'], as_index = False).agg({'Sales':['sum'],'Delivery':['sum']}).reset_index()
```

And then again combining both.

Can I do everything in one step in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass one dictionary with scalar function names and also list, but is necessary flatten MultiIndex and `rename` columns:

```
data_open_close_inv = (data.sort_values(['Date','Tank','Time'])
                           .groupby(['Date','Tank'])
                           .agg({'Sales':'sum','Delivery':'sum', 'Quantity':['first','last']})
                           .reset_index())

data_open_close_inv.columns = data_open_close_inv.columns.map(''.join)
d = {'Salessum':'Sales',
     'Delivery_sum':'Delivery',
     'Quantityfirst':'Open',
     'Quantitylast':'Close',
     }
data_open_close_inv = data_open_close_inv.rename(columns=d)
print (data_open_close_inv)
        Date  Tank  Sales  Deliverysum  Open  Close
0 2018-01-01     1    600            0  2900   2800
1 2018-01-01     2    400            0  2800   2704
2 2018-01-02     1    600           50  2900   2800
3 2018-01-02     2    400           50  2800   2704
```

Comment: Can we also count unique `Time` every date and tank level ? will it be `.agg({'Time': 'count'`})`?

Comment: @Neil - I think need `.agg({'Time': 'nunique'})`, [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html)

Comment: can we also get duplicate counts of `Time` in same aggregate function?

Comment: @Neil - If need all counts then `.agg({'Time': 'count'})`, if want count only duplicated `time`s use `.agg({'Time': lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).sum()})`

Comment: When i try to do following `'Time':['nunique'],'Time':lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).sum()})` It says `Dictionary key is repeated with different values`

Comment: @Neil - need `'Time':['nunique', lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).sum()]`